# How to route two grpc services using Istio virtual service and gateway

Tags: kubernetes, routes, istio, grpc-java

I have two grpc services (grpc-1 & grpc-2) in my project. I have deployed the grpc services on two different ports in openshift and created necessary configuration in Istio like gateway and virtual services.

I observed that at any time only one grpc service getting invoked as I am using "/" to route to services. I also tried to add context path like "/grpc-1" and "/grpc-2" but it didn't work.

Below is my code snippet from virtual services and gateway

grpc_gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: grpc-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

grpc-1-vs.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grpc-1-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.xxxx.zfjb.p1.openshiftapps.com"
  gateways:
  - grpc-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9014
        host: grpc-1
```

grpc-2-vs.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grpc-2-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "istio-ingressgateway-istio-system.apps.xxxx.zfjb.p1.openshiftapps.com"
  gateways:
  - grpc-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9015
        host: grpc-2
```

I am not able to route to two grpc services based on request url. Only one grpc service is being routed.

Comment: Using prefix /grpc1 and /grpc2 in different VS should work (you could use them in 1 VS). Could you add your curl requests and their responses ? With your current configuration it will access only one target.

Comment: Second above comment. Try different prefixes for different grpc endpoints. Having two different services behind the same endpoint does not make sense. If they do different things, they should be behind different paths (or hosts) and if they do the same, there is no point having two.